# Getting msg as "cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for the following parameters: Uri:" when installing laravel

Tags: docker, laravel-8

Getting msg as "cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for the following parameters: Uri:" when installing Laravel with docker. I used the command curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash in widows terminal.

[windows 10 (2004)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih5ft.png)

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have installed Docker Desktop https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop and WSL on Windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

In Docker Desktop, enable `Integration with additional distros` and select Ubuntu
[image]

Then make sure you use Windows Terminal https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701

In Windows Terminal, select Ubuntu, which opens up the terminal in Ubuntu, then you can run `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` successfully
[image]

Comment: not all heroes wear caps. You saved me!

Comment: Question is why don't they have THIS documented on the Laravel docker installation?

Comment: Can't believe this isn't part of the official docs. How tf is anyone supposed to figure that out without ending up exactly here?? Thank you sir/ma'am, looks like I owe you a warm whisky 

Comment: I had this exact thought. They should let people know with proper instructions to use laravel sail on desktop. since this is their default recommendations.

Comment: For others who may also be coming across issues with this, If you cannot see the ubuntu distro installed on docker desktop (for windows at least) you nee to run a powershell/cmd command to install it before it is available to select as a distro. 

`wsl --install -d ubuntu`

Answer (score 0):

I use the PowerShell terminal on Windows when I need to create a new project with Laravel. If I encounter the same problem, the main solution that can solve it is to install WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). In the Windows PowerShell terminal, you can simply type `wsl` after the command:

```bash
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

To start the installation process. And the process after installation is the same. Important comment that I also use Docker for this project.